# SSRS Columns Replicating when saved to CSV

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a bit of an odd issue with a simple report created in SQL Server Report Builder

There are 11 columns with the following labels:

- Invoice Number
- Account
- Date Invoice
- PO Number
- Invoice Description
- Quantity
- Product Code
- Price
- Blank (Texbox113)
- OMNI Code
- Blank (Texbox123)

The report generates perfectly, layout looks correct, saves to Excel perfectly.
However when saving to CSV the Columns seem to replicate strangely. I thought maybe it was from the groupings but from my poking around  can't seem to come right.

The column headers when saved to CSV are as follows:
(Note the duplication of Account Nbr, PO and Date Invoice)

- invoice_number
- Account_Nbr5
- Date_Invoice5
- PO5
- Account_Nbr2
- Date_Invoice2
- PO2
- Textbox54
- Account_Nbr3
- Date_Invoice3
- PO3
- Textbox107
- Account_Nbr6
- Date_Invoice6
- PO6
- Account_Nbr4
- Date_Invoice4
- PO4
- Account_Nbr
- Date_Invoice
- PO
- Invoice_Description
- QuantityToBill
- Unit_Price
- OMNI_CODE

I need the original 11 columns only, exported to CSV to pass to another application for import.

I've asked Google but there don't seem to be any queries which are similar to mine.

Any and all assistance and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For csv export, the header of a column is determined by the `DataElementName` property of the textbox which actually contains the data. If the `DataElementName` property is not explicitly set by the user, `DataElementName` automatically gets defaulted to the value of the `textbox.Name` property.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in commenting. This definitely helps in identifying where the column headers are coming from however I still don't understand why it's replicating the columns. There should only be the original 11 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether any conditional column grouping is there in your RDL. If so remove that and try to re-format the CSV in your code (client side code).
Also set DataElementName property for getting meaningful column names.